# If Address inherits from PhoneNumber, what OOP principle(s) does it violate?

Tags: oop, object-oriented-analysis, liskov-substitution-principle

There was a book that talks about have a `PhoneNumber` class, and then we would define an `Address` class that inherits from `PhoneNumber`, and I said at one time, that we can't do that, because an address is not a phone number, and to inherit, it must be a "is a" relationship.  Such as: a dog is an animal, and we we can make `Dog` inherit from `Animal`.

But since we have to follow [LSP -- Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), then the "is a" rule actually is not the determining factor here, because a square "is a" rectange (with width == height), but LSP says we can't define a `Square` class and inherit from the `Rectangle` class.  The simple explanation in English, I think, is the object `aRect` can respond to the message `setWidthAndHeight(w, h)`, but `aSquare` can't respond to it correctly and allow the whole program to run correctly.

So surprisingly, the `Address` class inheriting the `PhoneNumber` class violates the "is a" relationship, but it doesn't violate LSP.  Then formally, what OOP principle(s) does it violate?

Comment: the only thing it violates is common sense, but until one knows all the system and its components , one cant just judge a design based on 2 objects.

Comment: I thought the 5 principles of OOP: S.O.L.I.D. is that we don't just use common sense and do whatever we want but follow the principles

Comment: Hard to answer this question without knowing a few more details, but it seems like `Address` might have more than one reason to change if it inherits from `PhoneNumber`, which violates the Single Responsibility Principle.  Moreover, who said that SOLID were THE principles of OOP (consider GRASP, Law of Demeter, DRY, KISS).

Comment: What does 'THE' stand for?   :-)

Comment: The rectangle example only shows that not every "A is a B" should be designed as inheritance. However, it does not contradict the rule that every inheritance should be an "A is a B" relationship.

Comment: Why can't `aSquare` respond to `setWidthAndHeight(w, h)`?

Comment: @BobHorn It can respond, but violating the postcondition of `setWidthAndHeight`: If `w` and `h` are both positive numbers, the witdh and heigth of `aSquare` must equal to them, respectively.

Comment: @A.Rodas It wouldn't violate any condition if it threw an exception, or otherwise handled the call in a way that still kept the object a square. I'm not arguing for the fact that a square should derive from a rectangle, just that it can if you want it to, and are prepared to deal with how square handles the call.

Comment: @BobHorn I think the LSP is that the program should run correctly (and has no side effects).  So if one of `width` and `height` is ignored, then it is a side effect, or if the original program sets `height` to `0` and sets `width` to `750` so that it is a horizontal line, now all of a sudden, it becomes a big box of `750 x 750`, because the `0` was ignored as a result.

Comment: @BobHorn [It does](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle#A_typical_violation). If you throw an exception when `w` doesn't equal `h`, you are strengthening the precondition in the subtype, and that's not allowed according to the rules about preconditions and postconditions (Another reference: [p. 7 of this ObjectMentor article](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/lsp.pdf)).

Comment: @fab: An immutable square is a form of immutable rectangle (and also a form of a size-queryable square); both of those are in turn forms of a size-queryable rectangle.  No form of "square" object would likely be a form of a "rectangle whose size and width may be set to independent values", though many forms of square could be forms of a "rectangle which may be asked to set height and width independently, but may or may not honor such request exactly as given".

Comment: @supercat all true. But how does this refer to my comment?

Comment: @fab: The suitability of inheritance for a 'square is a kind of rectangle' relationship depends upon the type of square and the type of rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

**First, that really *does* violate LSP.**

Generally, you would not expect to be able to substitute Adresses for PhoneNumbers. That's the 'common sense' bit everyone is talking about in the comments.

The point of the OOP theory is that following the formal rules will *make your class robust* to things like change and strange use cases. Even if the book example doesn't actually break under an LSP violation, I imagine it would break very quickly if you tried to expand that class architecture. So, to avoid potential errors in the future of a class, you should follow LSP - even when choosing not to do so doesn't immediately break anything.

**Second, it violates ISP (the Interface Segregation Principle).**

This states that the set of methods available in a class should be the *minimum* required for objects of the class to function.

If the Address class inherits (or might reasonably inherit) a bunch of PhoneNumber methods that are never used when dealing with the actual street address (e.g. a getAreaCode() method, which would be undefined for house addresses), then its interface isn't minimal.

The gist of this is that OOP principles are really just guidelines. It's definitely possible to make up weird example code that violates a SOLID principle yet doesn't *actually* introduce bugs. That doesn't mean that you're getting around the rule; it just means you'll end up with many more bugs as soon as you try to expand the class.

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly two reasons to use inherits or extends.

1. reuse implementation (for DRY)
2. subtyping (LSP related)

I don't know all the principles but for your case it violates is common sense as @mpm commented.

Because even if your code satisfies all principles, it still can be inappropriate. In other words principles can not cover everything.